# Are there infinite extensions of $K$ inside $K^{ab}$ for $K$ local field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a local field. Let us define
$$
K^{ab} = \bigcup_{ \substack{ L  \subseteq K^{sep}  \\  L/K \ \text{ finite abelian } } } L . 
$$

1) I was just wondering are there any infinite abelian extensions $M/K$ contained inside $K^{ab}$? (other than $K^{ab}$ itself?)

2) For such $M$ does the corresponding Galois group $Gal(K^{ab}/M)$ finite index and open?

Thank you.

Comment: For 1), if $K = \Bbb Q_p$, you have $M= \Bbb Q_p(\zeta_{2^n})$ ; for 2) if $M/K$ is infinite then the index won't be finite.

Comment: Is my answer fine to you? If so, then you may accept it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The typical example is the maximal unramified extension. For $K = \Bbb Q_p$, you have $K^{\rm unr} = \Bbb Q_p(\zeta_n  \mid  (n,p)=1)$. On the other hand, $\Bbb Q_p^{\rm ab} = \Bbb Q_p(\zeta_n \mid n \geq 1)$ has ramification because of the $p^k$-roots of unity. Therefore, $K^{\rm unr}$ is an infinite abelian extension of $K$, strictly contained in $K^{\rm ab}$.

2) If $K \subset M$ is an infinite abelian extension, then 
$$\mathrm{Gal}(K^{\mathrm{ab}} / M) \leq \mathrm{Gal}(K^{\mathrm{ab}} / K)$$
is normal with quotient $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$, which is infinite, so the index can't be finite. 
While it is a closed subgroup, it is not an open subgroup, for the open subgroups in a Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ are exactly those subgroups of the form $\mathrm{Gal}(L/E)$ with $E$ being an intermediate field in $L/K$ of finite degree over $K$.

Comment: Sorry for the delay!